# marketing cloud - how to join my audience with subscribers having a distinct value

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, aggregate, data-views, group-by

I have an audience in a table called **wtab** which contains a column *mail*,
and I want to join it with the **subscribers** data view without duplicates.
when I have one 1 column I can use the DISTINCT keyword and it is behaving as expected

```
select DISTINCT w.Mail from  ENT._Subscribers as r 
JOIN wtab as w ON w.Mail = r.EmailAddress
```

but if I want to add a second column (*subscriberkey*) which is want I need
I cannot use the DISTINCT but I have to use an aggregate function because this is generating more values then expected.

```
select w.Mail, r.subscriberkey from  ENT._Subscribers as r 
JOIN wtab as w ON w.Mail = r.EmailAddress
```

so I tried with this

```
select r.emailaddress, r.SubscriberKey, count(r.SubscriberKey) from ENT._Subscribers as r 
JOIN wtab as w ON w.Mail = r.EmailAddress group by r.SubscriberKey
```

but I am getting this error:

*Error saving the Query field.Column 'C10958547._Subscribers.EmailAddress' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

How can I solve it and achieve a result with 2 columns and without duplicates?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do one of these two options:

**Using Row_Number() in subquery**

```sql
SELECT a.emailaddress,
a.SubscriberKey
FROM (
  select w.Mail, 
  r.subscriberkey,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY w.Mail ORDER BY w.Mail) as rn 
  from  ENT._Subscribers as r 
  INNER JOIN wtab as w 
  ON w.Mail = r.EmailAddress 
) a
WHERE a.rn = 1
```

This will only display the first match of subscriber with an email address that matches in the two tables. Anyone with the same email address will get a consecutive row number (rn) which means they will not meet the `rn=1` criteria and be excluded.

**Using GROUP BY with 'fake' aggregate functions:**

```sql
SELECT w.Mail, 
MAX(r.subscriberkey) as subscriberkey
from  ENT._Subscribers as r 
INNER JOIN wtab as w 
ON w.Mail = r.EmailAddress 
GROUP BY w.Mail
```

Using MAX() on a text field will only return the one that is the 'highest' in the alphabet. E.g. D is 'higher' than C. This will then let you use GROUP BY on just the single field because all other fields are aggregates. Your issue in your GROUP BY example is that you are including `r.emailaddress` in your select statement and it is not either in the GROUP BY nor an aggregate. Although this is possible in other versions of SQL, in the one SFMC uses anything not included in the GROUP BY statement must be an aggregate function.